# object 'panel.bpplot' not found error in R

Tags: r, lattice

I'm fairly new to R and I'm trying to create a **lattice** `bwplot`, however I'm getting an error saying `object 'panel.bpplot' not found`. I have tried using the following example from R documentation:

```
set.seed(13)
x <- rnorm(1000)
g <- sample(1:6, 1000, replace=TRUE)
x[g==1][1:20] <- rnorm(20)+3   # contaminate 20 x's for group 1

# default trellis box plot
require(lattice)
bwplot(g ~ x)
bwplot(g ~ x, panel=panel.bpplot, probs=seq(.01,.49,by=.01), datadensity=TRUE)
```

The result is that the first plot is created (`bwplot(g ~ x)`), but when second one tries to run I get:

```
Error in bwplot.formula(g ~ x, panel = panel.bpplot, probs = seq(0.01,  :
object 'panel.bpplot' not found
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`panel.bpplot` is function of package `Hmisc`, so you need to attach this package before plotting.

```
library(Hmisc)
bwplot(g ~ x, panel=panel.bpplot, probs=seq(.01,.49,by=.01), datadensity=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) Btw, for anyone else who has that problem, Hmisc is not part of the packages that come with the standard R installation, so you will have to install it and also load packages survival,splines,Formula before you will be able to load Hmisc